# {Java} Vaadin 14 - Limit user to 1 (one) active UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, vaadin, vaadin14

I posted this question [java-vaadin-14-detect-user-leave-closes-tab-f5-etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60084612/java-vaadin-14-detect-user-leave-closes-tab-f5-etc) but I think I asked the wrong questions.
I want to limit each signed-in user, to just one (1) active browser tab, or UI for that matter.

Someone told me to use `VaadinSession.getCurrent().getUIs()`, but this list is incremented by 1 (or 2 if `@Push` is enabled) every time the user refreshes the page. This means I can't check if this list contains more than one (or 2).

I'm lost on this! With native java applications and a built-in login system, I can EASILY limit each user to just one (1) session. It's harder with a browser. Or maybe it isn't?

Comment: I too am curious as to why you want to limit users to a single tab/window. If you explain a bit of your motivation, another solution may be suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe register a UI init listener which closes all other UIs in the same session whenever a new UI is initialized?

See:

- Tutorial: [*UIInitListener*](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/advanced/tutorial-ui-init-listener.html)
- [Javadoc](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/server/UIInitListener.html)

On the other hand, I would also be curious to understand why you want to prevent users from opening multiple tabs.